# How to nest both lists and sets in dict in python3.x?

Tags: python

I recently learned Python 3 and tried to define some complex data structures. Can someone help me with how to implement it?

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

d1 = defaultdict(dict)

d1['131']['all'] = [('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b'), ('3', 'c')]
d1['131']['uniq'] = ('a', 'b', 'c')

pprint(d1)

# var = {
#     'key': {
#         'all': [(),(),()],
#         'uniq': ()
#     }
# }

d2 = ???

num = [i for i in range(1, 27)]
ch = [chr(i) for i in range(97, 123)]

for i in num:
    d2[i]['all'].append((random.choice(num), random.choice(ch)))
    d2[i]['uniq'].add(random.choice(ch))

pprint(d2)
```

Comment: Can you provide *any* information as to what *specifically* you are trying to accomplish, and how the posted code relates to that?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want something that default initializes to a list if you call `append()` on it, and a set if you call `add()` on it?

Comment: It's hard to help you when we don't know what are trying to accomplish nor where you got stuck. please provide at least some information

Answer (score 2):

##### TL;DR

You can pass `defaultdict` a custom initializer that creates the structure you need. Scroll to my second answer for details.

##### My first answer: the manual approach

**Note** While my second answer might be more useful, I actually prefer the more manual approach to initializing the structure presented in this first answer, so I'm going to keep it here as an alternative solution.

There is no "list or set" data structure in Python. I think what you need to do is manage some of the logic manually yourself, deferring only part of the logic to `defaultdict`.

```
d2 = defaultdict(dict)

num = [i for i in range(1, 27)]
ch = [chr(i) for i in range(97, 123)]

for i in num:
    d2[i]['all'] = [(random.choice(num), random.choice(ch))]
    d2[i]['uniq'] = {random.choice(ch)

pprint(d2)
```

Later, if you need to modify `d2[i]['all']` for a value where you don't know yet if it's been initialized, you could use a test like:

```
if 'all' in d2[i]:
    d2[i]['all'].append(stuff)
else:
    d2[i]['all'] = [stuff]
```

or, since you initialize `'all'` and `'uniq'` as a pair, initialize them both on a condition like `if i in d2:`.

##### My second answer: give `defaultdict` a custom initializer

You can give `defaultdict` a function that initializes the sub-structure the way you want. You don't have to use an existing or built-in constructor. Since your default entry seems be a dict with `'all'` mapping to a list, and `'uniq'` mapping to a set, create a function that returns such a dict and pass it to `defaultdict`:

```
def my_initializer():
    return {'all': list(), 'uniq': set()}

d3 = defaultdict(my_initializer)
for i in num:
    d3[i]['all'].append((random.choice(num), random.choice(ch)))
    d3[i]['uniq'].add(random.choice(ch))

pprint(d3)
```

##### Lambda expressions: more concise, but more cryptic

If you want to make the code more concise, at the cost of making it more cryptic, you can use a lambda expression to do the same thing:

```
d3 = defaultdict(lambda: {'all': list(), 'uniq': set()})
```

Here I am creating an anonymous function with no argument that returns the empty entry you want, just like `my_initializer()` did. And I pass that anonymous function to `defaultdict` as the thing to use to create new entries.